# Sorting a 2D char array but by number

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers

I have been searching for a solution but can't seem to find one similar to mine. Am trying to sort
a 2D char * array by a certain column.

```
char *objs[50][3];

/***** within a loop to populate with values *****/
objs[count][0]=obj->level; //this is a number to be sorted
objs[count][1]=obj->cost;  //this is a number
objs[count][2]=obj->short_desc->str;  //this is a string
count++;
/***** end loop *********/

qsort(objs, count, sizeof(char *), compare_function); //to sort by obj->level, int values
```

i deleted my previous solution because it was showing all kinds
of weird numbers or not even sorting. i am not very experienced with
C, and would greatly appreciate help on how to do this.

thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your `compare_function`? Also, an array of structs seems more obvious to use than a double array of chars (in particular since you already have that struct defined for the right hand side).

Comment: Additionally to your `compare_function`, how is the structure `obj` points to defined?

Comment: Related to mafso's comment: you're assigning a number to the first 2 items in your secondary array, which is supposed to be pointers to a char. That won't work (basically, `char * objs[count][0] = <some float or integer>`). Make `objs` an array of structs.

Comment: You passing `sizeof(char *)` to `qsort()` suggests me that you are confused about your array's dimensions. The comparator function will get passed pointers-to-array of type `char *(*)[50]`.

Answer (score 0):

When sorting implicit structs in "C" defined by [2d arrays](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm), where each row corresponds to a single object, I find it useful to use [`qsort_s()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xc60xas%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) because it allows me to pass in more information about the the array entries to be sorted into the comparison function.

Thus the following accepts a 2d array of strings with `nRows` rows and `nColumns` columns and sorts on a column specified by `sortColumnIndex`.  The extra `context` pointer provided to `qsort_s()` communicates the sort index down to the sorting method without requiring global variables:

```
struct sort_on_index_context
{
    size_t nRows;
    size_t nColumns;
    size_t sortColumnIndex;
};

static int compare(void *p_vcontext, const void *ventry1, const void *ventry2)
{
    struct sort_on_index_context *p_context = (struct sort_on_index_context *)p_vcontext;
    char **entry1 = (char **)ventry1;
    char *s1 = entry1[p_context->sortColumnIndex];
    char **entry2 = (char **)ventry2;
    char *s2 = entry2[p_context->sortColumnIndex];

    return strcmp(s1, s2);
}

void sort_on_index(char **objs, size_t nRows, size_t nColumns, size_t sortColumnIndex)
{
    struct sort_on_index_context context;

    if (sortColumnIndex < 0 || sortColumnIndex >= nColumns)
        return; /* Print an error or throw an exception! */

    context.nColumns = nColumns;
    context.sortColumnIndex = sortColumnIndex;
    context.nRows = nRows;

    qsort_s(objs, nRows, sizeof(char *) * nColumns, compare, (void *)&context);
}
```

We pass `sizeof(char *) * nColumns` because we want `qsort_s` to treat each contiguous group of `nColumns` char pointers as single blocks to be rearranged in order.

And then you would call it something like this:

```
char *objs[50][3];
size_t nRows = sizeof(objs)/sizeof(objs[0]);
size_t nColumns = sizeof(objs[0])/sizeof(objs[0][0]);
size_t column_id_to_sort = 1; /* or whatever you want to define as your sort key. */

/* Fill up your "objs" array however you like */

/* Now do the sort: */

sort_on_index(&objs[0][0], nRows, nColumns, column_id_to_sort);
```

**Edit**

If `qsort_s` or some equivalent is not available in your development environment, you may need to communicate the necessary information to your sort function via a static variable, e.g.

```
static struct sort_on_index_context context;

static int compare(const void *ventry1, const void *ventry2)
{
    char **entry1 = (char **)ventry1;
    char *s1 = entry1[context.sortColumnIndex];
    char **entry2 = (char **)ventry2;
    char *s2 = entry1[context.sortColumnIndex];

    return strcmp(s1, s2);
}
```

**Update**

You can extend the method to supply your own custom comparison method like so:

```
struct sort_on_index_context_custom
{
    size_t nRows;
    size_t nColumns;
    size_t sortColumnIndex;
    int (*comparer)(const char *, const char *);
};

static int compare_custom(void *p_vcontext, const void *ventry1, const void *ventry2)
{
    struct sort_on_index_context_custom *p_context = (struct sort_on_index_context_custom *)p_vcontext;
    char **entry1 = (char **)ventry1;
    char *s1 = entry1[p_context->sortColumnIndex];
    char **entry2 = (char **)ventry2;
    char *s2 = entry2[p_context->sortColumnIndex];

    return p_context->comparer(s1, s2);
}

void sort_on_index_custom(char **objs, size_t nRows, size_t nColumns, size_t sortColumnIndex, int (*comparer)(const char *, const char *))
{
    struct sort_on_index_context_custom context;

    if (sortColumnIndex < 0 || sortColumnIndex >= nColumns)
        return; /* Print an error or throw an exception! */

    context.nColumns = nColumns;
    context.sortColumnIndex = sortColumnIndex;
    context.nRows = nRows;
    context.comparer = comparer;

    qsort_s(objs, nRows, sizeof(char *) * nColumns, compare_custom, (void *)&context);
}
```

And then call it like this to sort a given column of strings as integers:

```
static int integer_compare(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    int int1 = atoi(s1);
    int int2 = atoi(s2);
    return int1 - int2;
}

sort_on_index_custom(&objs[0][0], nRows, nColumns, 1, integer_compare);
```

Comment: `qsort_s()` is not standard and is only available on Windows. How do you know OP is using Windows?

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant - Well, apparently I don't, though in all places I've done portable "C" coding there has been a version of "sort" available with the extra argument.   If OP does not have that s/he will be forced to use a static variable.